# Functionals (based on domain and codomain)

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the following not a functional?

$$f(x,y)=(2x, 4y) \text{ for } V=\mathbb{R}^2$$

I know $f$ is linear, so I'm assuming there is a problem with $V$, the vector space, going to $F$, a field.

Comment: I would plug in x1+x2 in for x and y1+y2 in for y and would get (2x1+2x2, 4y1+4y2) which is equal to f(x1,y1)+f(x2,y2). Similar for scalar, so I know that in fact f is linear. So the error of why it is not a functional must be within the domain and codomain.

Answer (score 0):

A functional is a linear map to $\mathbb{R}$ in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is $(2x,4y)$ a real **number**?

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, then a functinal is a linear mappin $f:V \to F$.

Your $f$ above is a mapping $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: So can it not be a map from a field to a field? I thought ℝ2 was a vector space, I think that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @Joanne A field is a vector space over itself, so the domain *can* be a field (so in particular, a linear functional can map from a field to itself). But the codomain *must* be a field, by definition. $\mathbb R^2$ is not a field.